# How does one feed latent variables into a TensorFlow graph?

Tags: python, variables, tensorflow, placeholder

I want to use TensorFlow to train some latent (not available until run-time) variables. I am getting the following error: "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

I can obtain the expected results if I initialize 'a' with constant values, but my application does not allow the values of 'a' to be known until run-time, and I intend to use gradient descent to refine them after they become available. It looks like 'placeholder' provides this functionality, but I apparently need some help using them correctly. I want to know the right way to feed latent variables into a TensorFlow graph. Here is a simplified repro:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [2, 1])
b = tf.Variable(np.array([[1., 3.]]))
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

latent = tf.Variable(np.array([[2.],[3.]]))

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(sess.run(c, feed_dict={a: latent}))
```

Expected results:
[[ 2. 6.]
 [ 3. 9.]]

Actual results:
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things you can do. You can initialize the variable from a placeholder, and initialize it to a value fed to that placeholder.

```
import tensorflow as tf

latent_init_val = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [1, 2])
latent = tf.Variable(latent_init_val)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op, feed_dict={latent_init_val: [[2., 3.]]})
```

Or you can simply use the [`load`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load) method of the variable to set its value without using any additional objects.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Initial value only matters for shape here
latent = tf.Variable([[0., 0.]], dtype=tf.float64)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    latent.load([[2., 3.]], sess)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```py
feed_dict = {a: np.array([[2.],[3.]])}
```

You can't feed variables/tensors. Instead, you could evaluate the value of the variable first, and then feed it to a placeholder.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [2, 1])
b = tf.Variable(np.array([[1., 3.]]))
c = tf.matmul(a, b)

latent = tf.Variable(np.array([[2.],[3.]]))
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    latent_val = latent.eval() # <-- evaluate the value of the variable
    print(sess.run(c, feed_dict={a: latent_val}))
    # [[2. 6.]
    #  [3. 9.]]
```

Comment: Yes, that gives the expected results. Unfortunately, it also makes latent un-trainable.

Comment: You're right, missed that part of your question. Updated just now to keep `latent` as variable